# iTextSharp and QR Code sizing

Tags: .net, itext

I'm trying to create PDF's with QR codes on them using iTextSharp.  The issue I'm running into is that the size of the QR code changes depending on the content I pass into it.  Say I have the following code:

```
var val = "SER K250102 PNO 1011555-001 WGT 296.00 UNT LB";
//val = "SER K237706 PNO 1017401-001EJ08 WGT 365.00 UNT LB";

var barcode = new BarcodeQRCode(val, 100, 100, null);

var content = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

var image = barcode.GetImage();image.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
image.SetAbsolutePosition(100f, 100f);
image.SetDpi(600, 600);
content.AddImage(image);
```

If I pass in the first "val" variable to BarcodeQRCode(), the qr code is one size; however, if I pass in the second "val" variable (commented out, it only has 4 additional characters), the qr code size is significantly smaller.  Note that I am passing in a fixed height and width, and that I am setting an absolute position.

When I say the qr code is smaller, what I mean is that the overall height/width appears to be the same, but the margin around the code itself is much thicker, so the code itself is smaller.  Kind of like in HTML, where the width of a CSS element might be 100px, made up of a 90px content + a 10px margin.  Here, the "content" (qr code) is shrinking and the margin (the surrounding white space) is increasing.

Oddly, if I add more text to the "val" variable, the qr code size increases!

Even stranger, when I debug and watch the image variable for each of these scenarios, the properties are the same: same h/w, scale, etc.

Has anyone else experienced this fluctuating size?  Solved it?  Am I missing some setting or misunderstanding something about how qr codes are to render?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the size, so I checked the source code using different widths and heights.

So I found out, that it is 'til special sizes the same with bigger padding.
So I used 318 on both sizes for the best resolution.

I'm using itextpdf-5.5.6.jar (but i think it's relative the same thing).
I've found my solution in the `QRCodeWriter.class`, especially in the `renderResult()` method.

For example the first difference is between 105/106, next between 158/159 and so on.
The leftPadding is by this way 30/8, 34/12 and so on. The trick is the "multiple"-variable and the inputWidth based on the version of the qrCode.

The version will be calculated by the `initQRCode()` method from the `Encoder.class`

"numInputBytes" - 121
"ErrorCorrectionLevel" - M
"mode" - Mode.BYTE

So in my case it's version 7 and the inputWidth is (17 + 4 * version = 45).

According to your comment I wrote some more informations.

I use `Jaspersoft® Studio` to create my invoices. In the class the code looks like this -> `java.awt.Image qrCode = new BarcodeQRCode(qrCodeDataString, 318, 318, hints).createAwtImage(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE);`.
In the variable `hints` are the options for `ERROR_CORRECTION` and `CHARACTER_SET` and on the invoice there's an image square with 74px * 74px.
So all qrcodes look the same way, equal whether the string has 60 or 160 characters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! But I'm not quite following. Did you wind up making a code change to the source, or to your custom code that calls it? I'm wanting the QR code sizes to be consistent but they are bouncing all over the place.

Comment: also in the same boat, i'm having a hard time following your calculation for getting the width, given the input width.  The barcode doesn't fill the container, and it changes height/width depending on encoded text.